# Where can i find the annotations for the api.order.search controller?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

I need to write a new api endoint, very similar to the `api/search/order` endpoint using a custom implementation. Basically i want to add a new response format for another system.

This will also be a new route like `api/custom/search/order`.

My approach is that i want to write a new controller by extending the existing controller, defined as follows:

```
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                                                 |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | api.order.search                                                                      |
| Path         | /api/search/order{path}                                                               |
| Path Regex   | {^/api/search/order(?P<path>(?:\/[0-9a-f]{32}\/(?:extensions\/)?[a-zA-Z-]+)*\/?)$}sDu |
| Host         | ANY                                                                                   |
| Host Regex   |                                                                                       |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                                                   |
| Method       | POST                                                                                  |
| Requirements | path: (\/[0-9a-f]{32}\/(extensions\/)?[a-zA-Z-]+)*\/?                                 |
|              | version: \d+                                                                          |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                                                       |
| Defaults     | _controller: Shopware\Core\Framework\Api\Controller\ApiController::search()           |
|              | _routeScope: array (0 => 'api',)                                                      |
|              | entityName: order                                                                     |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler                               |
|              | utf8: true                                                                            |
+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

From my current setup i was able to write a new controller but the controller can not be found in the routes as there is no `annotation` in the original one. I could add a custom annotation but i was looking at the original definition and actually there is no annotation.

```
    public function search(Request $request, Context $context, ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory, string $entityName, string $path): Response
    {
        [$criteria, $repository] = $this->resolveSearch($request, $context, $entityName, $path);

        $result = $context->scope(Context::CRUD_API_SCOPE, function (Context $context) use ($repository, $criteria): EntitySearchResult {
            return $repository->search($criteria, $context);
        });

        $definition = $this->getDefinitionOfPath($entityName, $path, $context);

        return $responseFactory->createListingResponse($criteria, $result, $definition, $request, $context);
    }
```

My question is: Is there something like a dynamic annotation which will automatically be created? I can not find any information about how the path for `/api/search/order{path}`  is defined.

```
/**
 * @Route(defaults={"_routeScope"={"api"}})
 */
class OrderActionController extends ApiController
{

    public function search(Request $request, Context $context, ResponseFactoryInterface $responseFactory, string $entityName, string $path): Response
    {
  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to extend the core endpoint for that? Can't you add a custom route that that produces the format you need?

Because as i see it there is no was in symfony to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: I did write a custom endoint but still need the annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure it out. The annotations for the `api.search.order` are defined in the class `Shopware\Core\System\CustomEntity\Api\CustomEntityApiController`.

Shopware uses a dynamic annotation which will be used to create the routes. I was looking for a specific annotation and therefore was not able to find it.

```
  @Route(
      "/api/search/custom-entity-{entityName}{path}",
      name="api.custom_entity_entity.search",
      requirements={"path"="(\/[0-9a-f]{32}\/(extensions\/)?[a-zA-Z-]+)*\/?$"},
      methods={"POST"}
  )
```